# phantomjs screenshot not scaling to page content

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a couple of banners from client (eg - width 160 px and height 600 px) but when I try to take screenshot I see a result as an image 400x600 with white background (or black when result file is JPEG) and banner on a left side (about 160x600). I can't hardcode **viewPortSize** because all banners are different.
Is it possible to dynamically set **viewPortSize** or something to have result picture exactly like banner?

```
const page = require('webpage').create();
const system = require('system');
/**
 *  FIRST ARG - name of this runner
 *  SECOND ARG - input html file
 *  THIRD ARG - destination
 */
if (system.args.length !== 3) {
    console.log('Usage: phantomRunner.js [inputFile] [destination]');
    phantom.exit();
}
const inputFile = system.args [1];
const outputPath = system.args [2];

page.open(inputFile, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        page.render(outputPath);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

I have already tried decrease viewPortSize to 10x10, but it was not helpful.

EDIT
I found out that its impossible to change browser width to size lower than 360 and its a problem.

Comment: I think at the time of screenshot these banners are not rendered yet. You need to set some delay before `page.render`

Comment: @MysterX nope... its loaded and I see ad, add 1 second delay but result the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to have result picture exactly like banner?

In other words you would like to make a screenshot of a given element only. Here's not a full script to do that, just the important part.

```
var banner_id = system.args [1];

var b = page.evaluate(function (banner_id) {
    return document.getElementById(banner_id).getBoundingClientRect();
}, banner_id);

page.clipRect = {
    top:    b.top,
    left:   b.left,
    width:  b.width,
    height: b.height
};

page.render(system.args [2]);
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but I will inject some div element with banner_id between body and first child and do the same, because I don't know what would be in banner. Thanks a lot, it was helpful!